# 32-bit implementation of AES encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to implement AES. I currently have implemented `subByte()`, `shiftRow()`, `mixColumn()`, `addRoundkey()` and generation roundkey of 8-bit AES, and that is working. But its performance is not good.  So I want to implement 32-bit AES in software, but generating the extended s-box is confusing me. How does data entering as 8-bit come out as 32-bit? I can't find a 32-bit implementation of AES in software.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading the [Design of Rijndael book](http://www.amazon.com/Design-RijndaeL-Encryption-Information-Cryptography/dp/3540425802%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIIBINOD46VC3JCLQ%26tag%3Dws%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D3540425802) -- it is a superb text and _extensively_ covers optimizations for 8 bit _and_ 32 bit processors. Further, [DJB's Salsa20 optimizations](http://cr.yp.to/snuffle.html) have optimized versions of his Salsa20 algorithm for different processors which you may find useful to study. (Maybe not.)

Comment: The standard openssl implementation is 32 bit, and is open source. You pack 16 byte blocks into 4 32-bit words, and the "S-boxes" are then the combination of subByte (4x), shiftRow and mixColumn applied to groups of 4. I also recommend the book on the Design mentioned above.

Comment: Have you signed the Foot-Shooting agreement? http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html

Comment: @markus - There is another way.. good recommendations @samold - Thanks I will consider that :) @henno - You gave a clue to this problem. @crazyscot - I can't understand what's the Food-shooting. but the site is good!!

Comment: Deep within that site there is a slide entitled "Foot-shooting prevention agreement". The point is, you should not implement crypto algorithms unless you understand the ways that implementations - which seem perfectly correct in that they pass their test vectors - can be attacked.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest implementing it in a bit sliced manner. Bit sliced implementations do not only scale very well, they have also very good properties regarding timing attacks. I know this requires a redesign of your functions. And a performance gain can only be archived if you calculate multiple AES operations in parallel.

The fastest AES implementation (without Intel AES instructions) is bit sliced: 
http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/129

With Google you will also find the source code.